# How can I tell if moodle cron is working?

Tags: php, cron, moodle

I've just sended a messege to the server admin asking if he can set the cronjobs on the server and he asked me to tell him if everything is working right. How can I test whether the cronjobs are working or not?

Comment: For future viewers I wrote an article detailing the Moodle cron job: http://www.coursebit.net/moodle-cron-job/

Comment: @Joe the site doesn't work anymore, here's the [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171119224402/http://www.coursebit.net/moodle-cron-job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to output Moodle cron run to the logfile, e.g. your cron.d record may look like:

```
* * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php /var/www/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >> /var/log/vle/moodle-cron.log 2>&1
```

Then, the content of `/var/log/vle/moodle-cron.log` will tell you immediately if cron running fine. If you want to go further, you can even monitor the file for the last update using some monoring tools and get alerts if cron has stopped.

Answer (score 3):

It's true —as edelgado said— that if the cron job hasn't run since 24hours there will be a message in the notification page.

However, if you want to run immediately the script, you could just go to:

```
http://www.mymoodlesite.com/admin/cron.php
```

Where `www.mymoodlesite.com` is the address of your moodle instance.

The page will show the output of the script as it is run by the server. If anything works as it should it will print similar lines at the end of the page:

```
Cron script completed correctly
Execution took 1.938528 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Notifications page.
If the cron did not run in the last 24h it will show you a message informing about that fact.

Comment: There isn't any notifications... and I would like to test the cron immediately after setting the server

Comment: If you are admin in moodle, there has to be a notifications link, on top of the administration section. If you want that kind of validation program your cronjob to write a log file. From this file's timestamp you can verify the last time it ran.

Comment: Yes, I´ve found the Notifications section. But it doesn't have anything to show. I´m going to try with the logs!

Answer (score 0):

I am running WAMP 2.2.  I used [this moodle doc page](https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Cron_with_Windows_OS), specifically the **moodle cron package**.  Downloaded the  MoodleCron-Setup.exe file, installed and verified that the Windows service was active and running.  The name of the Service is **Moodle Cron**. If the status says Started - then you should be all set.  If you double click on the service and view its properties, it should have a startup type of Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check it from the following, if you are the site administrator of the moodle.
Login to your moodle, and then
Dashboard ► Site administration ► Server ► Scheduled tasks

It will show you the status of each task. There you should know whether the cron job runs.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The last cron exec timestamp is in the table "mdl_config_plugins", with field "plugin" = "tool_task", so to query the value (in PHP format):

```
select value from mdl_config_plugins
where plugin='tool_task' and name='lastcronstart';
```

To show this value in Site Adminsitration / Notification page, modify the file admin/**renderer.php** around line 307, inserting the following 2 lines after the "cron_infrequent_warning" line:

```
$lastcron = get_config('tool_task', 'lastcronstart');
$output .= " Last CRON exec = ".date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$lastcron)."<br>";
```